# I will not map proper url in html page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

**when I hit this url**

```html
<a href="/cart/pk">Cart<span>{{request.session.cart|length}}</span></a>
```

I got error "The current path, cart/, didn't match any of these."

so please tell how map proper url

**my url.py file:**

```
path('cart/<int:pk>',views.cartitem,name='cart'),
```

**My cartitem.py file:**

```
def cartitem(request,pk):

cart=request.session.get('cart')
if cart is None:
    cart=[]

for c in cart:
    tshirt_id=c.get('tshirt')
    product_id=c.get('product')
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,pk=pk)
    tshirt=Tshirt.objects.get(pk=pk)

    c['size']= Sizevariant.objects.get(tshirt=tshirt_id, size=c['size'])
    c['tshirt']=tshirt
    c['product']=product

return render(request,"cart.html",{'cart':cart,'product':product,'tshirt':tshirt})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `/pk` instead of the primary key of the cart. Since `int` has as pattern a sequence of digits, that thus fails. You should inject the value for the primary key, for example with:

```
<a href="/cart/{{ some_product_pk }}">
```

where you replace *`some_product_pk`* with an expression that determines the primary key of the product you want to render. But it is better to work with the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<a href="{% url 'cart' pk=some_product_pk %}">
```